# Remove white space at the bottom of telerik RadComboBox

Tags: c#, telerik, radcombobox

I'm using three telerik RadComboBox 
But I see some white space at the bottom of last element of combo box.

Height is dynamic even for 6 items sometimes there is white space, also sometimes it shows scroll bar for 1 item and sometimes it does not show scroll bar.

Have seen some old post for this but they do not have solutions.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, You will be needing to play around with the PopUpTemplate of RadComboBox.  IMO, the Popup that telerik uses might have a fixed height set hence you are getting white space when you have few items bound.

Regards,

Arun Selva Kumar